# Any alternative to vino, x11vnc, and x0vncserver?

Tags: xorg, software-recommendation, vnc

I like to use vnc to connect to an existing session/display on my ubuntu machine, either actual or virtual (like created with Xvfb). I need to set it up through terminal and ssh, i.e. I do not have access to the machine.

I have explored 3 options but each lack a feature I need.

1. vino:

   Works fine, but it does not seem possible to only send a portion of the display with something like a -Geometry option.
2. x11vnc:

   Works fine, but the `-repeat` bug is a bummer. It is explained under `-repeat` option [here](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/x11vnc_opts.html).
3. x0vncserver:

   Works very well and I thought this is the one I have been looking for. However, the clipboard does not get synced between host and server as mentioned [here](https://github.com/TigerVNC/tigervnc/issues/529).

So, are there any other options? I do not want to use TeamViewer of NoMachine and I like to have gnome ubuntu dekstop.

Answer (score 1):

Try X2Go.
`sudo apt-get install x2goserver x2goserver-xsession`
Clipboard is working fine, resolution is dynamically changing and one of the best features - it is completely free. 
More info here:
[X2Go Wiki page](https://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/start)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I looked at the documentation and it says it is not compatible with GNOME 3.12 and later. [Here](https://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/doc:de-compat) is the link. I will edit the question to mention that I like to have gnome desktop.